# How to send android.location.Address with intent as putextra

Tags: android, android-intent, static, bundle, start-activity

Is it possible to put an instance of `android.location.Address` with `Intent` to another activity?

```
Address current_location;
```

I mean, I am trying to put current_location directly with the intent by:

1. `IntentName.putExtra("current_location",current_location);`
2. or indirectly by a bundle:

   ```
   Bundle b = new Bundle();
   b.put....("current_location",current_location);
   IntentName.put(b);
   ```

If none of the above strategy support "Address" then what should be the best approach to pass the Address instance to another activity? 
If I declare,
`public static Address current_location;`

and try to access it from another activity then there is no guarantee that Android will hold current_location data. Or am I wrong?

In such situation, what approach should be followed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to pass it through as a parcelable.  By looking at the API, I think they already conform to the standard.

Address
extends Object
implements Parcelable

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

So to package it up and send it you would do:

```
    String key = getResources().getString(key);

    startActivity( new Intent()
                        .setClass(this, YourActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(key, current_location )
    );
```

Then to reassemble it in your activity you would do:

```
   String key = getResources().getString(key);
   Address current_location = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(key);
```

The **key** is simply the name you use to store the parcelable under.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether you'd be able to pass an Address (see below), but why not just pass the longitude and latitude (both `double`s, which can be placed as extras) and then reconstruct it in the next Activity?

Address does seem to implement the `Parcelable` interface which means you may be able to send it as `intent.putParcelable(key, address)`.

Comment: That won't work for me, as to the Activity class that I am sending data to is to aid the user to find best possible search result, so I need every possible info from the Address instance.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried the `Parcelable` approach? I haven't used it much, but I'm sure you'd be able to find a guide on here.

Comment: I have already tried it and it worked. I appreciate your guideline